# Reading double-precision floating point numbers from a file?

Tags: c, string, file, double

My problem is pretty simple; I have text file filled with double precision floating point numbers which I need to read in and store in a matrix.  I know how to open the file but from there I'm not sure how to parse out the data and convert it.  The numbers are separated by spaces and newlines and each is preceded by a sign (either '+' or '-').  I'm not sure which function (scanf, fgetc, etc.) I should use to read in the data.  I'm not new to programming though this is my first time working extensively with C.  Detailed explanations are welcome as I'd like to get more familiar with how tasks like this are handled.  Thanks!

Edit: Should have clarified that the file is generated by code so no need to worry about users messing with it.  Also From reading the docs it seems like I could just use fread to load all of the contents of the file into a string and then use atof to parse out each double.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double d;
scanf("%lf", &d);
```

scanf will skip the white space chars and let you read all values in a simple loop.  If you are reading from a file then fscanf should be your choice.

[scanf documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) and [fscanf documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/)

Comment: So there's no need to convert the variable?  I thought it was necessary to use something like atof or strtod since the pointer was just to a string matching the format pattern

Comment: scanf will parse input according to what you put into it's first argument - in this example "%lf" would parse a double value, "%d" an int, "%s" a string and so on.  There is no need for those other functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use fgets **AND** sscanf and their return values like,

```
char line[100];
while( fgets( line,100,filepointer ) )
  if( 1==sscanf(line,"%lf",&adoublevariable) )
    printf("%f",adoublevariable);
  else
    puts("not a double variable");
```

Comment: Why go through fgets and sscanf and not use fscanf directly?

Comment: @maarons: because the file may have been edited and ... users are not trustworthy ( *one user replaced a dot with a comma in one value* )

Comment: And who said that the file is given by an untrusted user, or was not checked before for compatibility?  In some cases you'd be right, but question was just how to read the doubles from a file.

Comment: @pmg In some European countries commas are used to separate decimals.

Comment: @Arc676: yes, people do that in Portugal! It's a PITA! The solution is to use *locale*s or transform the input beforehand or give an error and hope users start using sane formats.